# Incorrect css url in vue-cli electron build

Tags: vue-cli

I'm working on a project where I need to output both an SPA build and an Electron build using vue-cli. The issue I have is that the urls that webpack rewrites for css url function (@font-face, background-image etc.) are incorrect for the Electron build. Fonts work correctly in the SPA build.

- The url in the output css ends up as `app:///fonts/TFArrowMedium.de0bf1ed.ttf`
- The url in the output css should be `app://./fonts/TFArrowMedium.de0bf1ed.ttf` or `/fonts/TFArrowMedium.de0bf1ed.ttf`, both of which will load the correct file

The files are getting resolved and copied correctly, its just the rewritten urls that are incorrect. If I use inspector from inside electron and edit a background image from `app:///image.jpg` to `app://./image.jpg` then the image shows up correctly. URLs without the protocol at the front also work such as `/image.jpg` but if I try write that in my actual sass files then the build fails as it can't resolve the file.

Relevant dependencies:

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-beta.1",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.4",
"electron": "^12.0.2",
"sass": "^1.32.7",
"sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
"vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^2.0.0",
```

I would guess the issue is with `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` I assume it is the only thing that would be prepending `app://` to my urls but I'm not sure how I would go about fixing it.

I would be happy to just put all these assets in my public folder and prevent css url rewriting completely if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Thanks to this post, I found this page.

https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#changing-the-file-loading-protocol

With adding `customFileProtocol` in `vue.config.js` , the resources worked fine in production builds.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      customFileProtocol: "./",
    },
  },
});
```